# bash array element count operation in ansible

Tags: linux, bash, ansible

Wondering how this might work in ansible task?

```
 - shell: |
     y=(aa bb); echo "${#y[@]}"
   register: r
```

Currently it gives the following **error**

> ERROR: There was an error while parsing the task 'shell y=(aa bb); echo "${#y[@]}"\n'.
>        Make sure quotes are matched or escaped properly

..that's because of the character '#'. I can't escape it because otherwise that's an invalid bash operation. If I escape it, I get:

```
$ ansible -c localhost -m shell -a 'y=(aa bb); echo "${\#y[@]}"' -i hosts.ini test-host

 localhost | FAILED | rc=1 >>
 /bin/sh: ${\#y[@]}: bad substitution
```

The current equivalent result of this op on a linux cmdline is:

```
$ y=(aa bb); echo "${#y[@]}"
2
```

this seems to be an issue as I have tried all quoting combinations. I've opened an issue here, just in case: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/16968

A similar easier example that runs in bash, but not in ansible is:

```
$ a="aaa"; echo "${#a}"
3
$ ansible -c localhost -m shell -a 'a="aaa"; echo "${#a}"' -i hosts.ini test-host
```

> ERROR! failed at splitting arguments, either an unbalanced jinja2 block or quotes: a="aaa"; echo "${#a}"

**UPDATE:**

As described in the github issue hyperlinked in the question, the version I wanna use this with, is `ansible==1.9.6`.

@konstantin-suvorov's answer below works with ansible 2.1+ following jinja templating's comment system. In case you're wondering how to get around this problem of getting length of the array with older ansible versions, this one-liner might help:

```
y=(aa bb cc); g=("${!y[@]}"); res=`expr ${g[-1]} + 1`; echo $res
```

The workaround is to first get the indices of all elements using `!` instead of getting count with `#`. Apparently `!` gives no problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{#` is a comment sequence in jinja, so you variable ends up with unbalanced comment block.

You can workaround this by templating `{` before `#`:

```
- shell: |
         y=(aa bb cc); echo "${{"{"}}#y[@]}"
```

Update: full example:

```
$ansible --version
ansible 2.1.1.0
$cat xx.yml
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - shell: |
             y=(aa bb cc); echo "${{"{"}}#y[@]}"
      register: result
    - debug: var=result.stdout
$ansible-playbook xx.yml
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************
TASK [command] *****************************************************************
changed: [localhost]
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "result.stdout": "3"
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for adding this to my knowledge, but I'm afraid it still doesn't work!

> fatal: [localhost] => error parsing argument string 'y=(aa bb); echo "${#y[@]}"', try quoting the entire line.

Comment: I've pasted full example to the answer. It works. May be you want to try oneliner `- shell: 'y=(aa bb cc); echo "${{"{"}}#y[@]}"'`

Comment: I think that's because of your ansible version. I tested this on 1.9.6 and 2.1.0.0.. yours seems to be 2.1.1.0 ... So I upgraded and ran the same. The upgrade however seems to be broken as I get ```"NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined" in ansible/inventory/__init__.py", line 736, in _find_group_vars_files``` (anyway that's another issue).. I need to stick to older ansible version since I'm running this with python

Comment: when did you upgrade to 2.1.1.0 ? just curious

Comment: ahh crap I upgraded from pip3. Ansible doesn't fully support python3. I now upgraded with pip2 and it works. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Hm... i think you have something broken, this works with 2.1.0.0 just well.

Comment: yeah you're right. it works with 2.1.0.0 too now. My default pip is pip3 and so it broke earlier. Too much confusion. I'll accept this since it is possible in newer ansible versions. While my issue here https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/16968 is still valid for an earlier version. I'm now in a fix since I gotta use python to run the playbook. Gotta find another workaround.

Answer (score 0):

As Konstantin Suvorov mentioned:

> `{#` is a comment sequence in jinja, so you variable ends up with unbalanced comment block.

A colleague of mine suggested to use a variable as a workaround. For example, in this way:

```
 - shell: |
     y=(aa bb); y_length=#y[@]; echo "${y_length[@]}"
   register: r
```

In this manner, you do not have to use `{#`.